# Rendering web view on Android devices is taking a longer time than expected for some websites while using flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, android-webview

I am rendering webview with the help of flutter_inappwebview package in my flutter project but when it comes to android devices it is taking longer time(more than one minute) to load the web page, but it works fine with ios devices.

I have try changing the package from flutter_inappwebview to webview_flutter but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.